# Should the Enbseries mod for Skyrim be tagged enbseries or skyrim-enbseries?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was browsing the [new tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) and found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126960/adding-foreground-blur-to-enbseries-dof-in-skyrim).  As best I can tell, the enbseries tag should actually be a skyrim-enbseries tag, because that's the convention:  gamename-modname rather than just modname.  However, in this case, [Enbseries](http://www.enbdev.com/doc_en.htm) is apparently made for multiple games.  Does that change anything?

In general, what approach should I take with something like this where I can see two reasonable approaches?  Should I go ahead and make the change?  Should I always ask on meta?  Does it matter that I know next to nothing about Skyrim or Enbseries?  How do you resolve things when you see something that looks broken but aren't sure?

Comment: Its usually never wrong to ask on meta, so long as you check for similar/related answers first :-). 

As for the tag itself, I think its fine separated. Realistically there's not going to be a lot of questions about it to justify separating them all into game-specific sub-tags.

Comment: @Robotnik, can you post that as an answer so that people can choose between it and murgatroid99's answer?

Comment: Done :-) (15 chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its usually never wrong to ask on meta, so long as you check for similar/related answers first :-). As for the tag itself, I think its fine separated. Realistically there's not going to be a lot of questions about it to justify separating them all into game-specific sub-tags.

In either case, RavenDreamer has now [removed the tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/126960/revisions). His [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126960/adding-foreground-blur-to-enbseries-dof-in-skyrim#comment172626_126960):

> While you are more than welcome to ask about ENBSeries on Arqade, I
>   don't believe an HD Graphics mod warrants its own tag.

Comment: In which case, surely mods only for a specific game (e.g. Skyrim's Falskar or Minecraft's Feed the Beast) don't need to be tagged as skyrim-falskar and just simply falskar would do? We need to be consistent, meaning this tag needs to follow the same conventions.

Comment: @shanodin - but that's the point, its not a game-specific mod. If it comes to the point where we have 50 questions, all about the skyrim version, then we should retag them. As it stands, we have 1 question. We also don't usually add sub-tags unless its a specific area of expertise for that game, like tf2-<character name>, or as you mention, minecraft-feed-the-beast.

Comment: @shanodin - In either case, RavenDreamer's just removed the tag entirely, making it a moot point

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the change should be made. Even if this mod exists for multiple games, there are probably some differences between the different versions. Therefore, I think we should not treat them as the same thing, so we should prefix the tag with the game name as you suggest.

Comment: The differences are quite minor. Some games merely have more features as the mod has been developed more on the particular game. The configuration will still work the same way.